# Windows PGM socket access error with non-admin account

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, pgm-protocol

I'm trying to use PGM sockets to send data on Windows. I can listen and receive data fine from a PGM socket using a non-admin account, but when I try to create a socket to send data I get an exception at this step:

**socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));**

The exception is:

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Note that if I run the same code under an admin account it works fine. Is there a way to create a sender PGM socket without running under an admin account?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  I don't quite understand why admin is required for PGM.  It's very frustrating.  I have found no information on the internet that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a solution to this. Seems like admin privileges are required.